# Creating table and calculation of min from txt file

Tags: python

I am to ask a user to submit a txt file for evaluation, I then need to setup a table and calculate certain things(max, min, sum, etc) where i am stumped, is how to setup the table i am to print and how to possibly find the max,min, and sum based on column specifications.

my code so far ----

```
def main():    
    my_list = [[float(i) for i in line.split(',')] for line in open("Alpha.txt")]
    print(my_list)
    my_list_one = my_list[0]
    my_list_two = my_list[1]
    my_list_three = my_list[2]
    my_list_four = my_list[3]


main()
```

All that this has done, is read the Alpha.txt file and divided the lines of data into individual lists. 
What i am striving to do is put them in a table like so...

```
-----------------------------------------------
|     |   A   |   B   |   C   |   D   |   E   |
-----------------------------------------------
|   1 | 5.00  | 2.00  | 6.00  | 4.00  | 5.00  |
|   2 | 3.00  | 7.00  | 8.00  | 7.00  | 9.00  |
|   3 | 1.10  | 2.20  | 5.80  | 0.10  | 1.30  |
-----------------------------------------------
```

for the table formatting, would i just use basic string formatting like

```
my_str = "| {:>12.10f} | {:^3d} | {:>12d} |".format(10**(-i), i, 10**i)
```

furthermore i am unsure as to how i can take a user submitted lette, ex A and calculate the min of 5.00, 3.00, and 1.00 unless i create an if else for every possible choice depending on column or row.

Any help is appreciated!

my current program would print out

```
[[1.2, 4.3, 7.0, 0.0], [3.0, 5.0, 8.2, 9.0], [4.0, 3.0, 8.0, 5.6], [8.0, 4.0, 3.0, 7.4]]
```

Comment: You should look at [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/) if you're going to be doing a lot of stuff like this

Comment: Totally agree with using pandas; you could knock this out in 10 minutes once you've got a bit of experience with it. Also, please add `if __name__ == "__main__":` above the `main()` call; it allows you to import the script as a module.

Comment: really? wow, im very new to python so this is all new to me! ill check it out though, Thanks to both of you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like the others have mentioned, Pandas is a great library to use for data analysis. However, there is a bit of a learning curve for Pandas.  Your situation can be solved in a much simpler manner using CSV files and basis csv reading libraries ([csv library documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.DictReader)) instead.

**example of csv reading**

Here is a demonstration of how to read a basic csv file:

Lets create a basic CSV file and place it in the same directory as the code that follows.
If you were to open the csv file with a text editor it would look as follows:

```
data1,data2
1,6
2,7
3,8
4,9
5,10
```

Now lets create a few functions that we will use to read the CSV then do the operations that you are hoping to accomplish:

```
def read_csv_file():
    import csv, os
    this_dir = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
    csv_file = this_dir+"/sample_data.csv"
    data1_list=[]
    data2_list=[]
    with open(csv_file, 'rb') as csvfile:
        csv_reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile, dialect= 'excel')
        print "1st data row:"
        for csv_row in csv_reader:
            data1_list.append(csv_row["data1"])
            print csv_row["data1"]
            data2_list.append(csv_row["data2"])
    return data1_list, data2_list

def calculate_min(data1):
    from operator import itemgetter
    minimum_data1=min(enumerate(data1), key=itemgetter(1))[1]
    max_data1=max(enumerate(data1), key=itemgetter(1))[1]
    print "the min of the set was: %s"%minimum_data1
    print "the max of the set was: %s"%max_data1
```

you then can use these two functions as so in a main file:

```
data1, data2 = read_csv_file()
calculate_min(data1)
```

and you will get this output:

```
1st data row:
1
2
3
4
5
the min of the set was: 1
the max of the set was: 5
```

If you desire to do other operations, it would be best to see if there is a library that already does this, otherwise do it by hand.

I hope this helps!

-- Peter

Comment: could you do this without csv? im trying to teach myself python and i came upon this question. i was eager to find out how to solve it and it didnt mention the use of csv. But i will look into csv files!

Comment: the elements of the question are: user input, file parsing, data interpretation and manipulation. The way that @user2840144 was proposing is a way to do all of the file parsing by hand. But this is not necessary because there are other known formats (such as csv) that have parser libraries that come with a standard python install. If you are trying to find the quickest and easiest solution, csv would be the way to go. But if you are tying to learn things through writing your own text file parser, then that would be different.

Comment: Yes i was looking to do text file parsing but the csv like you said is much easier and efficient. Cheers!